# How to group array with key in object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one array with response like this:

```
let firstArray = {
        "TEST0":[
                    "App",
                    "Desktop",
                    "Mobile"
        ],
        TEST1": [
                    "BEVERAGES",
                    "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS"
        ]
    }
```

And I have array of objects like this:

```
 let secondArray =  [
        {
            created: "2019-05-28T11:13:55.000"
            createdBy: ""
            displayname: "BEVERAGES"
            docname: "BEVERAGES"
            id: 1
            name: "BEVERAGES"
            purposeCode: "P"
            responsible: (2) [{…}, {…}]
            shortname: "BEVERAGES"
            status: "Active"
        },
        {
            created: "2019-05-28T11:13:55.000"
            createdBy: ""
            displayname: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS"
            docname: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS"
            id: 2
            name: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS"
            purposeCode: "P"
            responsible: []
            shortname: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS"
            status: "Active"
        }
    ]
```

I want to check where that displayname from second array belongs in first array, and group them BY KEYS like that

For example :

if i have BEVERAGES, APP, and so i will have structure like this:

```
{
    "TEST0":[   
                "App",
                "Desktop",
                "Mobile"
    ],
    TEST1": [
                "BEVERAGES":[
                {
                    created: "2019-05-28T11:13:55.000"
                    createdBy: ""
                    displayname: "BEVERAGES"
                    docname: "BEVERAGES"
                    id: 1
                    name: "BEVERAGES"
                    purposeCode: "P"
                    responsible: (2) [{…}, {…}]
                    shortname: "BEVERAGES"
                    status: "Active"
                }
            ]

    ]
}
```

My question is different because i have two arrays and not one, where i want to make one array and group second array by keys from first array

Comment: There its only one array and he want to group, i have two arrays where i need to compare them and them group by keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newData = {}

Object.keys(firstArray).forEach(key => {
  newData[key] = firstArray[key].map(e => secondArray.find(i => i.displayname === e) || e);
})

console.log(newData);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xptrh5?file=index.js

Comment: you are good...tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem:

```
    var test = {
    TEST0:[
                "App",
                "Desktop",
                "Mobile"
    ],
    TEST1: [
                "BEVERAGES",
                "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS"
    ]
}
var arr = [
    {
        created: "2019-05-28T11:13:55.000",
        createdBy: "ZIRA",
        displayname: "BEVERAGES",
        docname: "BEVERAGES",
        id: 1,
        name: "BEVERAGES",
        purposeCode: "P",
        responsible: "(2) [{…}, {…}]",
        shortname: "BEVERAGES",
        status: "Active"
    },
    {
        created: "2019-05-28T11:13:55.000",
        createdBy: "ZIRA",
        displayname: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS",
        docname: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS",
        id: 2,
        name: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS",
        purposeCode: "P",
        responsible: "[]",
        shortname: "CLOTHING, PERSONAL ACCESSORIES AND RELATED PRODUCTS",
        status: "Active",
    }
]
var newArr = []
var count = 0
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(test)) {
  if(value.length){
    console.log(value);
    jsObj1 = {};

    value.forEach(function(singleKey , index){
        arr.forEach(function(singleObject){
            if(singleObject.name == singleKey){
 var jsObj1 = {};
                        var jsObj = {};//newArr[count] = {
              jsObj[singleKey] = singleObject;
                            //newArr.push(jsObj);
                        jsObj1[key] = jsObj;
                        newArr.push(jsObj1);  

            }
        });

    });
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

In `newArr`, you will get your desired array.

Comment: im getting error for Object.entries  that entries not exists

Comment: Try my updated code .

Comment: What kind of error you are getting ? @None

Comment: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: Run these function in your console . You will get the desired output .

Comment: i cant run it because it throwing me errors

Comment: Copy paste my code and have you tried to run in your browser's console ? @None

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198947/discussion-between-none-and-pushprajsinh-chudasama).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const result = {};
for (let testName of Object.keys(response1)) {
  if (response1.hasOwnProperty(testName)) {
     for (let i = 0; i < response1[testName].length; i++) {
      const key = response1[testName][i];
      result[key] = response2.filter(el => key === el.displayname)
     }
  }

}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i want all array not only TEST1 or TEST2.

Comment: ok, try updated code